# nivo slider - add text to the slider

Tags: jquery, html, slider

I am currently using the nivo slider on my homepage, to show different images. It works perfectly. Although, next to the images there are some text, which I would like to follow each picture.

Here is the HTML code:

```
     <!-- Splash -->
            <div class="splash">
              <div class="splash-content">
<div id="text1">                
<h1>More traffic to your website</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitectetur adipis. In ultrices malesuada est eu laoreet. Nullam eget tellus ac lacus bibendum egestas et at libero. Vestibulum commodo magna ut suscipit.</p>
</div>                
              </div>

            <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider nivo-right theme-default">
                <img src="images/splash.png" alt="" title="" />
                <img src="images/splash.png" alt="" title="" />
                <img src="images/splash.png" alt="" title="" />
                <img src="images/splash.png" alt="" title="" />

            </div>


        </div><!-- End Splash -->
```

As you can see in the HTML code, there is the `<div id="slider">`, which is the nivo slider. Although, I wish to have the `<div id="text1">` to follow each picture. Then have a `<div id="#text2">` to follow the next image and so on.

The jQuery code to control the nivo slider:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        effect: 'sliceUp', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `title` attribute in the `<img />` to define text to appear as caption in the slider.

---

Lets see an example:

```
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
    <img src="images/slide1.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="images/slide2.jpg" alt="" title="#htmlcaption" />
                                             <!-- ^ This is one way to bring caption -->
    <img src="images/slide3.jpg" alt="" title="This is an example of a caption" />
                                             <!-- ^ This is ANOTHER way -->
</div>

<!-- This part of caption is called from the second image link above see  `#htmlcaption` there -->
<div id="htmlcaption" class="nivo-html-caption">
    <strong>This</strong> is an example of a <em>HTML</em> caption with <a href="#">a link</a>.
</div>
```

---

#### Update

Without hacking the code, you can override the default class to appear as a separate text box.

Find `.nivo-caption` style and make some changes to it

```
.nivo-caption { 
       width: 200px; 
       height: 250px; 
       left: -200px; /* same as the width */
 }
```

#### Update 2

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/7Myy2/) with your slider working  with the workaround i mentioned.

SO far as this question goes, this is where i stop. Hope it helps.

Comment: I know I can add captions to the images, but that is not what I wish to achive. I wish to have a text placed next to the picture, which slides according to each image.

Comment: @user169691, thats exactly what it does. Try it

Comment: I am not sure I get it. Can you please modify your answer with a short example?

Comment: @user169691, Check the update, and please modify your name to proper one, from your profile page.

Comment: @user169691, Oh... Now i get it. Let me see what i can do

Comment: @oliverbj, Its a workaround, using caption as text area. see the update and do as mentioned.

Comment: There is not nivo-description class in the .css file. 
Beside of this, I wish to be able to add a text area to each image.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8956/discussion-between-starx-and-oliverbj)

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
 <div class="slide slide_0">
   <img class="slide-image" src='img1.png' width="100%"  title="#htmlcaption_0">
 </div>
 <div class="slide slide_1">
   <img class="slide-image" src='img2.png' width="100%"  title="#htmlcaption_1">
 </div>
 <div class="slide slide_2">
   <img class="slide-image" src='img3.png' width="100%"  title="#htmlcaption_2">
 </div>
</div>

<div id="htmlcaption_0" class="nivo-html-caption">
 <h1 class="slide-h1">Title</h1>
 <h2 class="slide-h2">Description</h2>
 <h3 class="slide-h3">
   <a href="#" title="">Learn More &raquo;</a>
 </h3>
</div>
<div id="htmlcaption_1" class="nivo-html-caption">
 <h1 class="slide-h1">Title</h1>
 <h2 class="slide-h2">Description</h2>
 <h3 class="slide-h3">
   <a href="#" title="">Learn More &raquo;</a>
 </h3>
</div>
<div id="htmlcaption_2" class="nivo-html-caption">
 <h1 class="slide-h1">Title</h1>
 <h2 class="slide-h2">Description</h2>
 <h3 class="slide-h3">
   <a href="#" title="">Learn More &raquo;</a>
 </h3>
</div>
```

Here's my css:

```
.nivo-caption {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  min-width: 550px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  z-index: 8;
}

.nivo-html-caption {
  display:none;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

[See this demo, they have captions.](http://demo.dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/)

Comment: I don't wish to have captions on the images. I have the text placed next to the image, I wish to have "full-slider" with both the text and the image.

Answer (score 0):

Put your text in the title and then you can make css changes to class `nivo-caption`, for example try giving width and float.

```
.nivo-caption{width:40px;float:right;}
```

Or else you can switch to other slider sorry.

[Here is link](http://www.serie3.info/s3slider/demonstration.html) is this what you looking for?