# slid image along with text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have done slid image

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript"> var i = 0; 
var path = new Array(); 
var i = 0; var path = new Array(); 
 path[0] = "one.jpg";
 path[1] = "two.jpg"; 


function swapImage() { 
document.slide.src = path[i];

if(i < path.length - 1) i++; else i = 0;

setTimeout("swapImage()",3000);

 } 
 window.onload=swapImage;
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
<img height="200" name="slide" src="image_1.gif" width="400" />
</body>
</html>
```

But now I tried to add 2 text

```
                          one is   "Good Day" it place on First(one) image

                          second is "bad day" it place on Second(two) image
```

But I don't know how to start "slide images along with text"

I want out put like below image add   text
                               "This is a caption"

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look in the following links:

http://wowslider.com/web-photo-gallery-subway-basic.html

http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/JavaScript/imageSlideShow.htm

One more solution you can place a `div` tag and inside it place your `text` this code:

```
<div>
    <img src="images/thumbnail-slider-1.jpg" />
    <div class="myCaption">blah, blah, blah</div>
</div>
```

wrap each image with a containing block, and place both your image and the caption within the wrapper.

See this post: [nivo slider - add text to the slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733527/nivo-slider-add-text-to-the-slider)

Comment: infotec thanks for Reply but i am not understanding that liks  please help me

Comment: In first link there is wow slider which you can use and in second link there is one demo which explain the text with image sliding.

Comment: thanks but u see my image in question i want like this please provide that type output like 
image on Text